# How can I prevent Undesired data from being added into the Queue?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, queue, stack

I'm wrote my code using combination of *stack* & *queue* data structures. My code is working, but I have a problem in the `main()` method.

I'm using a loop to read the input from the user. The loop will break when the user enters `"Exit"`.

The word `"Exit"` **shouldn't be pushed** to the stack, but in my code it's being pushed.

I've used `if` condition to break loop, but it didn't work.

*My code:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackQueue stackQueue = new StackQueue();
    int dataLength = 0, i = 0;
    Object data = "Start";
    System.out.println("Enter data or 'Exit' to exit:");
    while (!data.equals("Exit")) {
        if (data.equals("Exit"))
            break;
        else {
            data = input.nextLine();
            stackQueue.enqueue(data);
            dataLength++;
        } // else
    } // while loop

    System.out.println("The entered data is: ");
    while (dataLength > 0) {
        System.out.println("The data no." + (i += 1) + ": " + stackQueue.dequeue());
        dataLength--;
    } // while loop
}// Main Method
```

*My output:*

[image: Output]

Comment: Your while loop condition is `!data.equals("Exit")` so why would you put if codition for check `data.equals("Exit")`.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you check if the Input is "Exit" after you add it to the stack.
What you can do instead is get the input and only then test it.

```
data = input.nextLine();
while(!data.equals("Exit")){
            stackQueue.enqueue(data);
            dataLength++;
            data = input.nextLine();
    }
```

One more thing is that this test

```
if (data.equals("Exit"))
```

Is not doing anything because you already checked the input in the while loop condition which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you've listed any input provided by the user will be added to the queue. And the if input is equal to `"Exit"` the condition of the `while` loop will get triggered, i.e. your `if` statement will never get executed.

You need to change the first `while` loop by placing the *break-condition* right after the user input has been read and before storing the data into the queue.

To avoid redundancy, the condition of the `while` loop can be set to `true` because `if` statement will be responsible for exiting from the loop.

```
// your code
while (true) {
    data = input.nextLine();
            
    if (data.equals("Exit")) break;
            
    stackQueue.enqueue(data);
    dataLength++;
}
// your code
```

*Output with that change*

```
A
B
C
Exit
The entered data is: 
The data no.1: C
The data no.2: B
The data no.3: A
```

*Sidenotes:*

- Avoid using Object type when you know what the expected type will be, in this case, `data` has to be of type `String`;
- Instead of the strict comparison with `equals()` you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()`, so that both inputs "Exit" and "exit" will terminate the loop.
- It's a good practice to define constant values used in the code as `public static final` variables at the top of your *class*. And then refer to them by name. It saves you from excremental typo (while typing the value multiple times, you can misspell it somewhere) and gives you the advantage of quick access to these constants if you need to change them because they all will be grouped together instead of being scattered all over the code.